# Embed form and choice list

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, embedding

[image: Site form]

I have a form, SiteType, with an other form, DomainType, embbed. But when I tried to display in the site form the domain name field, which is a choice list, it appears 3 times (each list contains all the domains in the DB) instead of one time.

This is my SiteType :

```
class SiteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Nom du site',
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('nameBundle', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Nom du bundle du site',
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('numClient', 'integer', array(
                'label' => 'Numéro client du site',
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('domains', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new DomainType(),
            ));
    }
...
}
```

and my DomainType:

```
class DomainType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('domainName','entity', array(
                'class' => 'EliophotBackBundle:Domain',
                'property' => 'domainName',
                'label' => 'Nom du domaine'
            ));
    }
...
}
```

and the form where I display the form :

```
<form action="{{ path('site_create') }}" method="post">
  {{ form_row(form.name) }}
  {{ form_row(form.nameBundle) }}
  {{ form_row(form.numClient) }}

  {% for domain in form.domains %}
    {{ form_row(domain.domainName) }}
  {% endfor %}

  {{ form_rest(form) }}

  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Ajouter</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My SiteController :

```
public function newSiteAction()
    {
        $site = new Site();

        $repository = $this->get('doctrine')
            ->getRepository('TestBackBundle:Domain');

        $domains = $repository->findAll();

        foreach($domains as $domain) {
            $domainObject = new Domain();
            $domainObject->setDomainName($domain->getDomainName());
            $site->getDomains()->add($domainObject);
        }

        $newForm = $this->createForm(new SiteType(), $site);

        return $this->render('TestBackBundle:Site:new_site.html.twig', array(
            'site'   => $site,
            'form'   => $newForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

I would like to diplay only one choice list with all the domains name... How can I do this ?

Comment: We need to see the controller. My first guess would be that `Site` entity has already linked 3 `Domain` objects in DB.

Comment: Look pls, I edit my answer adding my controller :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can resolve this like this:

<kbd>**SiteType**</kbd>

```
$builder
    ->add('name', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Nom du site',
        'required' => true
    ))
    ->add('nameBundle', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Nom du bundle du site',
        'required' => true
    ))
    ->add('numClient', 'integer', array(
        'label' => 'Numéro client du site',
        'required' => true
    ))
    ->add('domains','entity', array(
        'class' => 'EliophotBackBundle:Domain',
        'property' => 'domainName',
        'label' => 'Nom du domaine',
        'multiple' => true
    ));
```

In this case you wouldn't have need for `DomainType`. As for the controller can you clarify this snippet:

```
$domains = $repository->findAll();

foreach($domains as $domain) {
    $domainObject = new Domain();
    $domainObject->setDomainName($domain->getDomainName());
    $site->getDomains()->add($domainObject);
}
```

Why are you fetching and then reconstructing all the domains? Are the `domains` from `Site` entityt **not of type** `TestBackBundle:Domain`? If they are in fact, you could just:

```
$domains = $repository->findAll();

$site->setDomains(new ArrayCollection($domains)); // don't forget sto `use` ArrayCollection
```

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: thanks :) so finally i'm not in the case of embed form ?

Comment: Yes it would seem that way. ;) Embedded forms are generally useful when you want to "embed" more than one fields, multiple times...